# Do I need to call ReleaseBuffer in this context?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, c-strings

I have been looking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(ATLSIMPSTR%252FATL%253A%253ACSimpleStringT%253A%253AGetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(CSTRINGT%252FATL%253A%253ACStringT%253A%253AGetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(ATL%253A%253ACSimpleStringT%253A%253AGetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(ATL%253A%253ACStringT%253A%253AGetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(GetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-160#getbuffersetlength) about `CSimpleStringT::GetBufferSetLength`.

It says:

> If you use the pointer returned by `GetBufferSetLength` to change the
> string contents, call ReleaseBuffer to update the internal state of
> `CSimpleStringT` before you use any other `CSimpleStringT` methods.
>
> The address returned by `GetBufferSetLength` may not be valid after the
> call to ReleaseBuffer because additional `CSimpleStringT` operations can
> cause the `CSimpleStringT` buffer to be reallocated. The buffer is not
> reassigned if you do not change the length of the `CSimpleStringT`.
>
> The buffer memory is automatically freed when the `CSimpleStringT`
> object is destroyed.

I am actually using `CString` but given this code:

```
CString strHostLabel = dlgLabels.GetTrimmedHostLabel();
CString strCoHostLabel = dlgLabels.GetTrimmedCoHostLabel();

MENUITEMINFO sInfo{};
sInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
sInfo.fMask = MIIM_STRING;
sInfo.cch = strHostLabel.GetLength();
sInfo.dwTypeData = strHostLabel.GetBufferSetLength(sInfo.cch);
SetMenuItemInfo(pMnuSwap->GetSafeHmenu(), SwapAssignment::Host, TRUE, &sInfo);
sInfo.cch = strCoHostLabel.GetLength();
sInfo.dwTypeData = strCoHostLabel.GetBufferSetLength(sInfo.cch);
SetMenuItemInfo(pMnuSwap->GetSafeHmenu(), SwapAssignment::Cohost, TRUE, &sInfo);
strHostLabel.ReleaseBuffer();
strCoHostLabel.ReleaseBuffer();
```

Since I do not modify the underlying data it seems I do not need to call `ReleaseBuffer`. Correct?

Comment: If you do not modify the strings then you don't have to call `GetBuffer`. Just cast away the `const` of LPCTSTR: `const_cast<LPTSTR>((LPCTSTR)strHostLabel)`.

Comment: @Dialecticus Thanks. But I still need to specify the `cch` property with the result of `GetLength`. So that, and your cast will still be OK?

Comment: Yes. `GetLength` and `(LPCTSTR)` peacefully coexist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The longer answer is: Don't call `GetBuffer`/`GetBufferSetLength` either. Call [`GetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getstring) instead. It will return a pointer to the immutable sequence of characters. This requires a `const_cast` as well, i.e.

```cpp
sInfo.dwTypeData = const_cast<TCHAR*>(strHostLabel.GetString());
```

This is due to the fact that [`MENUITEMINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-menuiteminfow) is used both for setting menu items, as well as reading information back. Since C doesn't allow you to specify transitive constness, the structure is forced to use non-const data members, even when the pointed-to data is never changed. The `const_cast` is both required as well as safe.

Also note that setting the `cch` member is not required. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-menuiteminfow) explains:

> [...] `cch` is ignored when the content of a menu item is set by calling [`SetMenuItemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuiteminfow).

Comment: Very informative. Thank you very much. I don't think I have ever used `GetString` in 20 + years!